# teardown doesn't affect MediaRouteButton

Tags: google-cast

In my Android sender I am doing the teardown exactly as described in [Android Sender Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender). The receiver is released OK, reverts to Chromecast Home Screen, but the status of MediaRouteButton doesn't change: it shows that my App is still conected. I need to click Disconnect there before I can connect again. How can I make MediaRouter to re-check the connection status after the teardown?

Thanks.

Comment: Where/how are you calling the teardown() code? Are you calling that after user selects disconnect fro the cast menu or you are doing in response to a certain event? Once I know how and from where you are calling that, I should be able to provide some better feedback.

Comment: I am doing it after user presses some button in my interface, not in the cast menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you need to handle various things that the ActionProvider would do for you automatically. After making sure that you are disconnected, call `mMediaRouter.selectRoute(mMediaRouter.getDefaultRoute())` and see if it does what you want.